# Calculating expected values and percentiles of continuous functions

Tags: statistics

Let f(X) be 1/(b-a) for [a,b] and 0 everywhere else.

Then X is uniformly distributed over [0,2]

Let Y = 2X+2 ; G = 6X^2 + 3 and H = exp(x)

Calculate 1. the expected value of Y

the 50% percentile of Y

the expected value of G

the expected value of H

the 75% percentile of H.

Attempt:

X has an expected value of (a+b)/2 = 1 = E(X) for the given interval. Now I know E(a+bX) = a+bE(X) which equals 4. However my book says 3. Am i wrong? I don't see how I could screw up something so simple...

So I need to find Q(0.5). Do I use the integral from 0 to x of Ydx for this? I don't really understand what to do here. Or transform Y = 2X+2 into X = 2Y+2 so Y = 0.5X-1, equal that to 50% and solve for X?

I got this one right, equals to 11.

Also correct: 0.5(e^2 - 1).

Here is where I get into trouble again like part 2. My book just isn't very clear on finding that value from continuous functions.

Can you help me out for 1,2 and 5 please?

Comment: Edit your questing using help from [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) Enclose mathematical operations with the dollar($) sign.

Comment: At the beginning of your question, I’m assuming that you mean the PDF of $X$ is the given $f(X)$, and that $a=0$ and $b=2$. Is that correct? If so, then you are correct, and your book is incorrect. $E[Y] = 4$, for exactly the reason you gave.

Answer (score 1):

Yes for part A you are right there must be typo in your book

$E(Y)=E(2X+2)=2E(X)+2=2(1)+2=4$

Hint for $1$ and $5$:For percentile you need $\int_{a}^{P_i}f_{Y}(y)=\frac{i}{100},\int_{a}^{P_i}f_{H}(h)=\frac{i}{100}$

You are on the right track you have to find the distribution of $Y=2X+2$ and $e^X$ (You know how to do transformations right ? )

For $E(G)=E(6X^2+3)=6E(X^2)+3 \ \ \  ,\ {E(X^2)}=\int_{x}x^2f_{X}(x)dx$

For $E(H)=E(e^{x})=\int_{0}^{2}e^xf(x)dx=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{2}e^xdx $

Thats it.